# How do I write this regex - word followed by number - in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I know this is simple but I am not able to get it right can someone help me?

I have a string like this

```
 ABC 345 and XYZ 3234 MN RT X 00 AM feb17
```

From this string I have to take out all the numerical values except feb17. My regular expressions are not working. Can someone suggest a way to write this regex in Java?

The out put should be -

```
 ABC and XYZ MN RT X AM feb17
```

Thank You,

PS: This is not my home work. Just trying to clean up a tweet.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, and we can help you understand where you've gone off-piste. :-) Although people can just give you the solution, if they can see where you went wrong, that's usually more helpful to you than just seeing their solution.

Comment: This is what I have tried -- (^([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}))|[^a-zA-Z#_:;\\-\\)\\(\\.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .replaceAll("(?<=\\s|^)\\d+(?=\\s|$)")
```

Comment: How does .replaceAll("\\b\\d+\\b") differ from your solution?

Comment: It is different 8-) But looks like it's working the same way (except `\b` word boundary is not matching spaces only).